# How to define a dynamic programming problem in an incomplete information game?

Tags: mathematical-economics, game-theory, bayesian-game, dynamic-programming, dynamic-games

How can I define a problem of dynamic programming, to use the Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman equation in order to solve the utility maximization problem of the generic agent of a dynamic game with incomplete information? Can anybody give apart from notes, books or some paper a simple example just for the definition of the problem?

Comment: Check out the textbook by [Mailath and Samuelson](https://web.sas.upenn.edu/gmailath/books/), particularly the section on Markov equilibrium.